# hide fields of model in Django

Tags: python, django

I want to hide some fields from my model, how can I do it?

something like :

```
class YourForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = YourModel
        exclude = ('check_out_time', )
```

this is my code:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'table'
        verbose_name_plural = "table1"

    name            = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False, blank=False, unique=True)
    description     = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    year            = models.IntegerField(null=False, blank=False, choices=get_list())
```

how can I hide field 'year'?

Comment: what do you mean "hide from my model"? hide where? `exclude = ('year', )` in your model form will work, so I'm not sure that's your question, since you gave this answer already.

Comment: I think you can use fields = ['name', 'description'] in your meta

Comment: I want to hide it from the user @dirkgroten

Comment: then just as you wrote, `exclude = ['year']` in your ModelForm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess, with this question, you meant that you want to hide certain fields from your form. You can easily do that using the below code:-

```
class YourForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = YourModel
        fields= ['name', 'description']
        #or
        exclude=['year']
```

But when will submit that form, make sure that it takes some default value or it accepts null/blank.

Comment: But instead of `fields = `, `exclude  = ['year']` is also the correct way, as mentioned by the OP himself. It's better, because that way if someone adds other fields to the model, they don't get excluded by default.